# Snowpipe : Load ordering is not guaranteed as per documentation

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The snowpipe document says that the loading order of files by snowpipe is not guaranteed since the queue can be processed by multiple processes - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html#load-order-of-data-files .

How do you overcome this if you need absolute ordering guarantee ?

Comment: You can't guarantee that when using Snowpipe, you would have to set up your own process that loads the table sequentially file-by-file in the correct order. Why do you need guaranteed ordering?

Answer (score 0):

A few options. ranging in difficulty/viability depending on your use case.

A) Redefine your use case. Ordering is hard to guarantee without sorts in most database systems.

B) Put files in your storage account in batches, one at a time, slowly enough that ordering is all but guaranteed. (could technically still have issues if something gets hung up for a long enough period of time)

C) Put a view or materialized view on top of your table that manages your ordering. (Performance considerations for ordering in a view. Cost considerations for ordering in a materialized view)

D) Set up a post processing step that takes your piped table and reorders it into another table. A Stream/Task pair would be useful for this, but you're streaming latency would be dependent on the schedule of the Task.

E) Set up a Task that 1) Queries the table for filename metadata 2) queriest the list of files from the stage. 3) compares the lists to figure out what file needs to load next 4) runs a copy into statement on that file specifically.
This also has the downside of the task, and the query to get a list of files can be slow depending on quantity of files, and it might have a hard time keeping up with your files if there are a lot of them.